# Robot java keypresser wont type in letters into command prompt administrator

Tags: java

The robot java keypresser wont type in letters into command prompt administrator here is my code below it opens up the start menu, types in command prompt and holds control+shift+enter then releases it then the user has to press yes and the code waits 5 seconds then should type in the letter A and by that time the command prompt administrator is open but it doesnt type in the letter A i have tested to see if i didnt open command prompt in time by incresasing the wait time to 15 seconds and it didnt work. i tried opening a jframe then closing it and then running the key press after the jframe closes and the jframe  opened closed went back to command prompt but still didnt type in any letters here is part of the code below Thank you:

```
public static void Command() throws AWTException, InterruptedException{   
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        Thread.sleep(200);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your Robot function properly on some programs, you have to run your code as admin.

Comment: what do you mean do i have to run the .jar file as administrator and if so how as when i right click on the jar file it just says open

Comment: @Cufe: If you already have the jar you can either open a cmd as admin and run your jar with `java -jar`, or wrap it in an .exe file and run it as admin normally. To wrap it you can use programs such as launch4j.

Or, if you're testing the code from Eclipse, you can start eclipse as admin and the code will automatically be run as admin as well.